# XLT does not parse the data in Saxon

Tags: xslt, saxon, xlm

Short about my aim. I want to parse a xlm file with Saxon and at the end get a text file with code.
Something like this:
function1(){
a+a;}
function2(){
b+b;}
function3(){
c+c;}
My Idea is to create Such code using `<apply>` template tag so that for each facing a `<tr>` tag, a text file would be fullfiled with necessary methods that are in `<td>` tags. For example for each first child of `<tr>` is a function1(). 
Here are the errors:

```
    Warning
      XTDE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /html/body[1]/table[1]
    Matches both
      "document-node()/element(Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html)/element(Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}body)/element(Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}table)" on line 71 of file:/C:/Users/fleonov/Desktop/test_for_thomas/Var_05_02/transfer_html.xsl
    and "document-node()/element(Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html)/element(Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}body)/element(Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}table)" on line 21 of file:/C:/Users/fleonov/Desktop/test_for_thomas/Var_05_02/transfer_html.xsl
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

          Use_Cases
          <br xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" 
xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
 xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" 
xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" 
xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" 
xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" 
xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" 
xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/><p 
xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" 
xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
 xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" 
xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" 
xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" 
xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" 
xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0"
 xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">function1()<br/>

    {<br/><br/>function1()<br/>
```

[image: The command line output]

But each time I see such thing(in different variations). 
Here is mine xlt and xml code:

```
<xsl:template  match="/html/body/table" >
<xsl:variable name="main_file" select="concat(lower-case(../h1),'_stimuli')"/>
<xsl:result-document href="{$main_file}.h" method="text">`
{

<xsl:apply-templates select="/html/body/table" />  //I put apply template here because it is not 
                                                      possible to use 
                                                      <template> inside a <result-document>





    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template  match="/html/body/table" name="code">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="/html/body/table/tr" />   

</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template  match="/html/body/table/tr" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child::td[2]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child::td[3]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child::td[4]" />
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child::td[2]">
    <br></br>
    <p>function1()<br></br>
    {<br></br>   
<xsl:value-of select="." /><br></br>
    }<br></br>
</p>
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="child::td[3]"><br></br>
<p>function2()<br></br>
{<br></br>
<xsl:value-of select="." /><br></br>
}<br></br>
</p>
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="child::td[4]"><br></br>
<p>function3()<br></br>
{<br></br>
    <br></br>
    <xsl:value-of select="." /><br></br>

}<br></br>
</p>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>


Here is mine html that I parse.

     <body>
      <h1>Use_Cases</h1>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>file_name</td>
            <td>function1()</td>
            <td>function2()</td>
            <td>function3()</td>
            <td>function4()</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>a+a;</td>
            <td>b+b;</td>
            <td>c+c;</td>
            <td>d+d;</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>


      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you are struggling with exactly. Do you want a single result? Or several ones? Is the output plain text or HTML? Is the input XML, HTML or something else (`xlm`?). If you want to show us any error messages then please include them as text in the question, screenshots of command lines are hard to read.

Comment: I want a single result in text file(output) with these 4 functions. As Input I have HTML file.  Next time I will of course provide errors as text)

Comment: Do you always have four functions in the second to fifth row? Or is that variable how many rows or functions there can be?

Comment: Yes, I will always have 4 functions in rows from 2 to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you want to process certain cells of a table that it should be easy:

```
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/table/tr[1]/td[position() > 1 and position() &lt; 6]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="td">
      <xsl:param name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="., '{', ../following-sibling::tr[1]/td[$pos + 1], '}'" separator="&#10;"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3c5/1. This creates plain text, I am not sure why your example tried to use `br` elements which would only fit into HTML output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, but the code example:
why is it written: &lt; 6]"/>'
position() function returns the current position for each iteration?
for what purpose have you used :./following-sibling::tr[1]/td[$pos + 1], ?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: XSLT is XML so to write the XPath condition `position() < 6` inside of an XML attribute you need to escape the less-than sign as `&lt;`. The following sibling row with the same cell index seems to contain the code of the function body you want to output together wih the function name contained in the first row, so the expression `../following-sibling::tr[1]/td[$pos + 1]` is used to collect the code of the function body.  `position()` in the template's parameter initialisation `<xsl:param name="pos" select="position()"/>` is the position in the currently processed node sequence.